# Unpredictable results with http.Client and goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm new to Golang, trying to build a system that fetches content from a set of urls and extract specific lines with regex. The problems start when i wrap the code with goroutines. I'm getting a different number of regex results and many of fetched lines are duplicates.

```
max_routines := 3

sem := make(chan int, max_routines) // to control the number of working routines 
var wg sync.WaitGroup
ch_content := make(chan string)

client := http.Client{}

for i:=2; ; i++ { 

    // for testing
    if i>5 {
        break
    }

    // loop should be broken if feebbacks_checstr is found in content
    if loop_break {
        break
    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {

        defer wg.Done()

        sem <- 1 // will block if > max_routines

        final_url = url+a.tm_id+"/page="+strconv.Itoa(i)

        resp, _ := client.Get(final_url)

        var bodyString string 

        if resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
            bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
            bodyString = string(bodyBytes)
        }

        // checking for stop word in content
        if false == strings.Contains(bodyString, feebbacks_checstr) {

            res2 = regex.FindAllStringSubmatch(bodyString,-1)
            for _,v := range res2 {
                ch_content <- v[1]
            }

        } else {
            loop_break = true
        }

        resp.Body.Close()

        <-sem

    }(i)
}


for {
    select {
        case r := <-ch_content:
            a.feedbacks = append(a.feedbacks, r) // collecting the data 
        case <-time.After(500 * time.Millisecond):
            show(len(a.feedbacks)) // < always different result, many entries in a.feedbacks are duplicates
            fmt.Printf(".")
    }
}
```

As a result len(a.feedbacks) gives sometimes 130, sometimes 139 and a.feedbacks contains duplicates. If i clean the duplicates the number of results is about half of what i'm expecting (109 without duplicates)

Comment: You are ignoring errors and have a data race around `loop_break`. Try fixing those issues first.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like you might be leaking variables into your closure that you don't think should be. You haven't given us all your code so there may be a problem we can't see. My guess is that `final_url` is defined outside the go routine and you're creating a race condition where 1 or 2 of your go routines think they've set `final_url` to the URL they're supposed to request but before they make the request another go routines sets it again. Then you have multiple go routines requesting the same URL and producing duplicates. It's just a guess since we don't have all the code.

Comment: Read about concurrency in go: https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/10

Comment: @CoreyOgburn this is the correct guess. I changed the logic where final_url is being declared inside goroutines and now i get predictable and correct results. Appreciate your help! If you post an answer i'll mark it as a correct one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a closure by using an anonymous go routine function. I notice your `final_url` isn't `:=` but `=` which means it's defined outside the closure. All go routines will have access to the same value of `final_url` and there's a race condition going on. Some go routines are overwriting `final_url` before other go routines are making their requests and this will result in duplicates.

If you define `final_url` inside the go routine then they won't be stepping on each other's toes and it should work as you expect.

That's the simple fix for what you have. A more idiomatically Go way to do this would be to create an input channel (containing the URLs to request) and an output channel (eventually containing whatever you're pulling out of the response) and instead of trying to manage the life and death of dozens of go routines you would keep alive a constant amount of go routines that try to empty out the input channel.

Comment: Thank you for more detailed answer. I'll try to rewrite the logic considering channels